# how to do edit in spring mvc using only 2 jsp pages

Tags: spring, jsp

My code below,

```
@RequestMapping("/employee/edit")
public ModelAndView editEmp(@RequestParam int emp_Id, @RequestParam boolean flag,
   @ModelAttribute Employee emp) {  

  emp = empService.getEmp(emp_Id);  

  List<String> cityList = new ArrayList<String>();  
  cityList.add("Hyderabad");  
  cityList.add("Secunderabad");  

  Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();  
  map.put("cityList", cityList);  
  map.put("emp", emp);  

  return new ModelAndView("employee", "map", map);  

 }
```